# How do I get unix.stackexchange.com to email me on responses/comments on my posts

Tags: discussion

How do I get unix.stackexchange.com to email me on responses/comments on my posts

does anyone know?

I've looked around in my profile settings and I am continuing to look.

Comment: Do you have email notifications activated in your email settings (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/265935)? You should see a section called "Email Settings" when you go into your account settings. Is that not shown?

Comment: ah it was set to daily... I changed to it 3 hours... any way to get them faster? Id like to get an email as soon as someone responds/comments on something.

Comment: Why not keep the tab open so you can get the notification? Emails are designed for asynchronous communication after all.

Comment: The Android/iOS apps can give you quick notifications, and on desktop you can keep the tab open, but there's no indication that there's a notification.

Comment: thank you gentlemen!